# Can't populate a List in a loop

Tags: apex, force.com, list

I have this below code where I am trying to populate the List **'facList'** in a loop will different facilities but its populating only the last facility multiple times. What am I missing here?
If I instantiate the class within the FOR loop, it works. But what is the issue with instantiating outside the loop?

```
public class HCPFacility{
            public String city{get;set;}
            public String address{get;set;}
            public String zipCode{get;set;}
            public String state{get;set;}
            public String stateLicNum {get;set;}
            public String stateLicDate {get;set;}
            public String telephone{get;set;}
            public String fax{get;set;}
    }
List<HCPFacility> facList = new List<HCPFacility>();
HCPFacility HCPfac = new HCPfacility();
for (integer i=1; i<=2; i++)
{
    HCPfac.city = 'City'+i;
    HCPfac.address = 'Address'+i;
    facList.add(HCPfac);
}
system.debug(facList);
```

The output that I am getting is

> USER_DEBUG [19]|DEBUG|(HCPFacility:[address=Address2, city=City2,
>   fax=null, state=null, stateLicDate=null, stateLicNum=null,
>   telephone=null, zipCode=null], (already output))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right now, your loop is modifying the same instance of `HCPFacility` in each iteration of the loop (and then storing that in the list).

Lists store *references* of the objects you place into them (rather that independent instances), so when you change a field of the object outside of the list (`HCPfac` in your case), you also end up changing the field inside the list as well.

Changing that behavior is simple enough

```
List<HCPFacility> facList = new List<HCPFacility>();
// My preference is to declare (and only declare) variables, that I'm going to use
//   inside of a loop, just outside of the loop.
// You could also initialize here, but there isn't much of a point in doing that
//   considering what comes next.
// Declaring variables outside of a loop like this is just my personal preference
HCPFacility HCPfac;
for (integer i=1; i<=2; i++)
{
    // On each iteration, create a new (independent) instance of HCPfacility.
    // This ensures that we won't be modifying fields of objects previously inserted
    //   into the list.
    HCPfac = new HCPfacility();
    HCPfac.city = 'City'+i;
    HCPfac.address = 'Address'+i;
    facList.add(HCPfac);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Derek! Wasn't aware of that Reference thing. It worked for me

Comment: Do you have proof that declaring the variable outside the loop is more performant?  I just tested it and found the two methods took almost exactly the same amount of time.  Declaring the variable in the loop also has some tangible benefits, like preventing accidental reuse later and letting the GC free up the heap space.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Not on hand, no, though I'm fairly sure I've tested it before. I won't be able to get back to this until Monday but, as I recall, there isn't a measurable difference until you get to around 10k - 100k loop iterations. Can you go into more detail about the conditions of your test? We could take this to chat if needed.

Comment: @DerekF https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66088/loop-variables-initialized-outside-v-inside-loop (I think I screwed it up and it's not on salesforce se chat :/)